# IntelliJ IDEA 13: Keyboard shortcuts to navigate stack trace after running tests?

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

When I run a test in IntelliJ IDEA 13.01 Ultimate, with any luck it just passes. In those rare cases (ha!) when I get an exception, though, it displays that exception on the right side of the `Run` context, as is shown  below:

[image: Run context with stack trace]

The up and down arrows between the two panes can walk you through the stack trace, which is great. And they claim to have a keyboard shortcut, `ctrl+alt+down` and `ctrl+alt+up`. But these shortcuts do not seem to work with any obvious workflow, and I always wind up forced to use my mouse. This is, in fact, the only time I have to use my mouse in my IntelliJ IDEA workflow. What am I doing wrong?

1. `shift-alt-F10` to select the test case I want to see.
2. The image below appears, except the two blue arrows are grayed out. This is true whether the editor window contains a relevant source file or not.
3. Using the mouse, click on an item in the stack trace.
4. The two arrows are now colored, and can be used by clicking on them. Their keyboard shortcuts, however, cannot be used.
5. The keyboard shortcuts seem to work occasionally, under conditions that I do not understand.

I am using the `ideavim` plugin--could that be an issue?

Comment: Did you try that shortcut with the ideavim plugin disabled?

Comment: I did, and it didn't seem to work. But trying it again, I found that it just wasn't exhibiting the behavior I expected, which is why it threw me off. If I have selected a single failed test method and navigate "down," I get the first failed method of the next test class. If I navigate up, nothing happens.

Anyway, that's interesting. I wonder if there is a way to remap that behavior so that it plays nice with the ideavim plugin.

Comment: sounds like a plugin idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known problem, feel free to vote for [VIM-176](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-176).

Comment: It looks like this is not a problem with idea-vim but rather with Intellij - without this plugin those shortcuts  ctrl+alt+down and ctrl+alt+up don't work either.

Comment: No, it was an issue in IdeaVim. It's just fixed in IdeaVim 0.49.8 EAP.